# Formatting columns with aligned subcontents

Tags: multicol

I have here a snippet of my document.

```
\section{Events}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Monday}
    \textit{10:15am–11:15am}\dotfill\ Panel 2\smallskip\\
    {Text here,\\
    text there}

    \vfill\columnbreak

    \subsection{Wednesday}
    \textit{9:00am–10:00am}\dotfill\ Panel 1\smallskip\\
    {Text over there}
    \newline % 3rd-line padding
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent\textit{12:45pm–1:45pm}\dotfill\ Panel 1\smallskip\\
    {Text down here}

    \vfill\columnbreak

    \noindent\textit{11:30am–12:30pm}\dotfill\ Panel 2\smallskip\\
    {Text everywhere}
\end{multicols}
```

It looks like this. It's more or less what I want it to look like.

[image]

Issue being that these columns continue indefinitely, and are subject to having entries moved and replaced. Clearly in the way I've structured things above, any little such adjustment is impractical. There is the added inconvenience that when a pair of entries are of different lengths, I have to pad the shorter else I get a mess like this.

[image]

My question then is: *How can I do this better?*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks like a table. Why don't you use one? Do you really need section-numbering here?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure where to start with a table. Can you be more specific? What package or environment would suit my example?

Comment: Please give a more complete example which shows the mess you are seeing. Like this, your MWE looks fine. And describe a bit more, how you want to use this thing. Why do you have days with section-numbers? Is this really intended?

Comment: There's not a mess, yet. But if you imagine the amount of overhaul necessary if I wanted to add an element at the _start_ of either of those lists after tens of entries -- that's what I'm trying to avoid. "Monday" and "Wednesday" should be distinct lists, I suppose, and then formatted together somehow.

Comment: As for section numbers, no; they're unimportant. At any rate I bet I could keep that separate.

Answer (score 2):

Only a preliminary solution -- I don't recommend the usage of 8 parameters however. I'll try to update with key-value syntax later on.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\timedisplayline}[2]{%
  \textit{#1} \dotfill\ #2 
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tableline}[8]{%
  \protect\subsection{#1} & \protect\subsection{#4}  \tabularnewline
  \timedisplayline{#2}{#3} &   \timedisplayline{#5}{#6} \tabularnewline
  \ifblank{#7}{}{#7} &   \ifblank{#8}{}{#8} \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}


\section{Events}

\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.4\textwidth}}}
  \tableline{Monday}{10:15am-11:15am}{Panel 2}{Wednesday}{9:00am-10:00am}{Panel 1}{Some text}{Other text}
  \tableline{Monday}{10:15am-11:15am}{Panel 2}{Wednesday}{9:00am-10:00am}{Panel 1}{}{} 
  \tableline{Monday}{10:15am-11:15am}{Panel 2}{Wednesday}{}{Panel 4}{}{}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Better solution

I've added key-values called `\lefttitle`, `lefttime`, `leftpanel` and `leftdescription` and their `\right...` equivalents. They are only shown if they aren't empty. The grouping of the cells prevents the need to explicitly clear them, but they are initally all empty.

This way, it's not necessary to remember which parameter is meant for which entry.

The best thing would be to use two separate commands for the left and the right table half.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{panelstuff}{lefttitle}[]{%
  \def\KVlefttitle{#1}%
}
\define@key{panelstuff}{righttitle}[]{%
  \gdef\KVrighttitle{#1}%
}

\define@key{panelstuff}{lefttime}[]{%
  \gdef\KVlefttime{#1}%
}

\define@key{panelstuff}{righttime}[]{%
  \gdef\KVrighttime{#1}%
}

\define@key{panelstuff}{leftpanel}[]{%
\gdef\KVleftpanel{#1}% 
}

\define@key{panelstuff}{rightpanel}[]{%
  \gdef\KVrightpanel{#1} 
}



\define@key{panelstuff}{leftdescription}[]{%
\gdef\KVleftdescription{#1}%
}

\define@key{panelstuff}{rightdescription}[]{%
\gdef\KVrightdescription{#1}%
}



\newcommand{\displaydescription}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1}[\@tempa]%
  \ifnum\@tempa > 0 
  #1%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand{\displaytitle}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1}[\@tempa]%
  \ifnum\@tempa > 0 
  \protect\subsection{#1}%
  \fi%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\timedisplayline}[2]{%
  \fullexpandarg
  \StrLen{#1}[\@tempa]%
  \StrLen{#2}[\@tempb]%

  \ifnum\@tempa > 0 
  \textit{#1}\fi
  \ifnum \numexpr\@tempa + \@tempb > 0 % Only show a dotted line if at least one of the entries is available
  \dotfill\ %  
  \fi
  \ifnum\@tempb > 0 
  #2%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother


\presetkeys{panelstuff}{}{%
  lefttitle={},
  righttitle={},
  lefttime={},
  righttime={},
  leftpanel={},
  rightpanel={},
  leftdescription={},
  rightdescription={}
}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\tableline}[1]{%
  \setkeys{panelstuff}{#1}%
  \displaytitle{\KVlefttitle} &   \displaytitle{\KVrighttitle} \tabularnewline
  \timedisplayline{\KVlefttime}{\KVleftpanel} &   \timedisplayline{\KVrighttime}{\KVrightpanel} \tabularnewline
  \displaydescription{\KVleftdescription} &   \displaydescription{\KVrightdescription} \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}

\section{Events}

\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.4\textwidth}}}
  \tableline{lefttitle=Monday,lefttime={10:15am-11:15am},leftpanel={Panel 2},
    righttitle={Wednesday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1},leftdescription={Some text},rightdescription={Other text}}
  \tableline{lefttitle=Tuesday,lefttime={10:15am-11:15am},leftpanel={Panel 2},
    righttitle={Wednesday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 4}}

  \tableline{lefttitle=Tuesday,leftpanel={Panel 2},
    righttitle={Wednesday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1}}

  \tableline{leftpanel={Panel 17},
    righttitle={Thursday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1}}

  \tableline{righttitle={Thursday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1}}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another, updated version with possible formatting changes and some configurability

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter


\newif\ifusedotfill
\usedotfillfalse


\newif\ifdisplayifempty
\displayifemptytrue


\newcommand{\displaydefaultpanel}{%
  n.y.d.% not yet determined 
}

\newcommand{\displaydefaultdescription}{%
  N.A.% Not Available
}


\newcommand{\displaydefaulttime}{%
  t.b.a% to be announced
}

\newcommand{\displaydefaulttitle}{%
  N.Y.D.% Not Yet Determined
}


% Define both a \left... and a \right... key 
\newcommand{\definekeypair}[1]{%
  \define@key{panelstuff}{left#1}[]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname KVleft#1\endcsname{##1}%
  }%
  \define@key{panelstuff}{right#1}[]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname KVright#1\endcsname{##1}%
  }%
}

\define@key{panelposition}{position}[left]{%
  \gdef\KVposition{#1}%
}


\newcommand{\definekeypairformat}[1]{%
\definekeypair{#1}%
% Define the format key pair too
\definekeypair{#1format}%
}

\definekeypairformat{title}
\definekeypairformat{time}
\definekeypairformat{starttime}
\definekeypairformat{endtime}
\definekeypairformat{description}
\definekeypairformat{panel}


% Generic formats for the individual parts

\newcommand{\GenericDescriptionFormat}[1]{%
  \textnormal{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\GenericTitleFormat}[1]{%
  \protect\subsection{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\GenericTimeFormat}[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\GenericPanelFormat}[1]{%
 \textsc{#1}%
}

%%%% Individual formats for the right and left content

\newcommand{\LeftDescriptionFormat}[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\RightDescriptionFormat}[1]{%
  \textcolor{brown}{\textnormal{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\RightTimeFormat}[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{\textit{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\LeftTimeFormat}[1]{%
  \textcolor{DarkGreen}{\textit{#1}}%
}


\newcommand{\LeftPanelFormat}[1]{%
 \textsc{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\RightPanelFormat}[1]{%
 \sffamily {#1}\normalfont%
}


\newcommand{\LeftTitleFormat}[1]{%
  \protect\subsection*{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\RightTitleFormat}[1]{%
  \protect\subsection*{\textcolor{Green}{#1}}%
}


%%%%

% 'Generic' display format 
\newcommand{\@@showwithlocalformat}[3][position=left]{%
  \setkeys{panelposition}{#1}%
  \expandafter\csname KV\KVposition #2format\endcsname{#3}%
}%


% 
\newcommand{\@@decidewhattoshow}[3]{%
  \ifnum #1 > 0%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{#2}% preset with some value.
  \else\ifdisplayifempty\xdef\@@stringtoshow{#3}\fi%
  \fi%
}



% Display the description

\newcommand{\displaydescription}[2][position=left]{%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{}%
  \fullexpandarg%
  \StrLen{#2}[\@tempa]%
  \@@decidewhattoshow{\@tempa}{#2}{\displaydefaultdescription}%
  \@@showwithlocalformat[#1]{description}{\@@stringtoshow}%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{}%
}

% Display the title

\newcommand{\displaytitle}[2][position=left]{%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{}%
  \fullexpandarg%
  \StrLen{#2}[\@tempa]%
  \@@decidewhattoshow{\@tempa}{#2}{\displaydefaulttitle}%
  \@@showwithlocalformat[#1]{title}{\@@stringtoshow}%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{}%
}

% Display the time




\newcommand{\displaytime}[3][position=left]{%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{}%
  \fullexpandarg%
  \StrLen{#2}[\@tempa]%
  \StrLen{#3}[\@tempb]%
  \@@decidewhattoshow{\@tempa}{#2}{\displaydefaulttime}%
  \@@showwithlocalformat[#1]{time}{\@@stringtoshow}%
  \ifusedotfill%
  \dotfill\ %
  \else%
  \hfill\ % No dots here...
  \fi%
  \@@decidewhattoshow{\@tempb}{#3}{\displaydefaultpanel}%
  \@@showwithlocalformat[#1]{panel}{\@@stringtoshow}%
  \xdef\@@stringtoshow{} % 'clearing' the definition
}


\makeatother


\presetkeys{panelstuff}{}{%
  leftdescriptionformat=\LeftDescriptionFormat,
  rightdescriptionformat=\RightDescriptionFormat,
  lefttimeformat  = \LeftTimeFormat,
  righttimeformat = \RightTimeFormat,
  leftpanelformat  = \LeftPanelFormat,
  rightpanelformat = \RightPanelFormat,
  lefttitleformat  = \LeftTitleFormat,
  righttitleformat = \RightTitleFormat,
  lefttitle={},
  righttitle={},
  lefttime={},
  righttime={},
  leftpanel={},
  rightpanel={},
  leftdescription={},
  rightdescription={}
}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\tableline}[1]{%
  \setkeys{panelstuff}{#1}%
  \displaytitle{\KVlefttitle}               &   \displaytitle[position=right]{\KVrighttitle}              \tabularnewline
  \displaytime{\KVlefttime}{\KVleftpanel}   &   \displaytime[position=right]{\KVrighttime}{\KVrightpanel} \tabularnewline
  \displaydescription{\KVleftdescription}   &   \displaydescription[position=right]{\KVrightdescription}  \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}

\section{Events}

\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.4\textwidth}}}
  \tableline{lefttitle=Monday,lefttime={10:15am-11:15am},leftpanel={Panel 2},
    righttitle={Wednesday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1},leftdescription={Some text},rightdescription={Other text}}
  \tableline{leftdescriptionformat=\GenericDescriptionFormat,lefttitle=Tuesday,lefttime={10:15am-11:15am},leftpanel={Panel 2},    righttitle={Wednesday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 4}, leftdescription={And now for something completely different!}}
  % Now use an example, where the right time format is the same as the left one
  \tableline{lefttitle=Tuesday,leftpanel={Panel 2}, righttitle={Wednesday},
    righttime={9:00am-10:00am}, rightpanel={Panel 1},righttimeformat=\LeftTimeFormat}
  \tableline{leftpanel={Panel 17},
    righttitle={Thursday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1}}
  % Now use the Generic title format for the right title
  \tableline{righttitle={Thursday},righttime={9:00am-10:00am},rightpanel={Panel 1},
    righttitleformat=\GenericTitleFormat,leftdescription={One ring to rule them all}}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sigur: I am trying to improve my answer, that's why I omitted the screen shot

Comment: OK. Please, feel free to remove, if necessary. I just inserted because I liked it. Congs.